# xp_cmdshell copy commands fails to copy files that doesn't have extensions

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem in which I need to copy files that doesn't  have extensions but I can't do using standard 'xp_cmdshell copy ' command,**any suggestions?**

Comment: Why you can't do it? What happens?

Comment: Works fine when I tried it, can you be more precise as to what problem you encounter?